# How to dequeue en element from my custom queue

Tags: c, pointers, queue

As an exercise, I'm trying to create a basic queue. I've got a problem in my `deQueue` method.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int Task;
typedef struct QueueNode_ QueueNode;
typedef struct TQueue_ TQueue;

struct QueueNode_ {
    QueueNode* next;
    Task task;
};

struct TQueue_ {
    QueueNode* first;
    QueueNode* last;
};

TQueue* initializeQueue(){
    TQueue* queue = NULL;
    queue = malloc(sizeof(TQueue));
    queue->first = NULL;
    queue->last = NULL;
    return queue;
}

void enQueue(TQueue* q, Task t){
    if(q->first == NULL){
       q->first = malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));
       q->first->task = t;
       q->first->next = NULL;
       q->last = q->first;
    } else {
        QueueNode* node = malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));
        node->next = q->last;
        node->task = t;
        q->last = node;
    }
}

void printQueue(TQueue* q){
    QueueNode* node = q->last;
    printf("LAST->");
    while(node != NULL){
        printf("%d->", node->task);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("FIRST\n");
}

QueueNode* deQueue(TQueue* q){
    QueueNode* temp = q->first;
    QueueNode* newFirst = q->last;
    q->first = NULL;
    while(newFirst != NULL){
        newFirst = newFirst->next;
    }
    q->first = newFirst;
    return temp;
}

int main(){
    TQueue* queue = initializeQueue();
    enQueue(queue, 1);
    enQueue(queue, 2);
    printQueue(queue);
    QueueNode* node = deQueue(queue);
    printf("%d\n", node->task);
    printQueue(queue);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected my `deQueue` method to remove the head of my queue. But that's not the case apparently.

Here's the output:

```
LAST->2->1->FIRST
1
LAST->2->1->FIRST
```

I suspect my `deQueue` method to not replace the head of the queue with the second element but I though I was doing this with `q->first = newFirst;`, so I'm a bit stuck.

Just if it's not clear I would expect it to print:

```
LAST->2->1->FIRST
1
LAST->2->FIRST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might could do it like this:

```
QueueNode* deQueue(TQueue* q){
    QueueNode *tmp = q->last;

    while(tmp->next != q->first) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    // new first is now the old second element
    q->first = tmp;

    // new firsts' next still points at 
    // old first so we free that memory here
    free(q->first->next);
    q->first->next = NULL;

    return tmp;
}
```

Don't forget to free your memory.

You can test it here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: Yep, that does the trick! Do you know why my current implementation didn't work?

Comment: The `while`-condition seems to be the problem. You were iterating until the end of the list but you should stop one element before that.

Comment: Yes but by doing `q->first = NULL;` just before the while, I would expected it to stop one element before, that's why I don't understand..

Comment: Well you should take a close look at your code. You are setting e.g. `temp = q->first` but then you are setting `q->first = NULL` which makes `temp` also `NULL` which means you always return `NULL` here. Beside that you should be careful not losing the last pointer to free the memory for that node you are dequeueing (silly word ^^). And I think it does not do what you are expecting because `newFirst->next` has never been changed. You are setting `q->first = NULL` but the nodes themself still got valid `next` pointers.

Comment: Ok I got the point but you are saying that I'm always returning NULL right? So why it prints 1 in my output when doing `printf("%d\n", node->task);`? It should stop the program here right if it was returning null? (`printf("%d\n", node==NULL);` output 0).

Comment: Oh sorry my bad I just made the same mistake I tried to make you aware of. You are in fact not doing anything with your queue. You set `temp = q->first` and return that address at the end straight away. so `deQueue` will *always* return the pointer to the first element. Then you are setting `q->first = NULL` which has no effect since you are iterating through the hole list assigning `q->first = newFirst` in the end which is the same pointer as it was before. So you do *nothing* with the list. You could just write `QueueNode * deQueue(TQueue *q) { return q->first; }` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: No I need to "delete" the first element of queue ^^, so I can't do `QueueNode * deQueue(TQueue *q) { return q->first; }`

Comment: No of course you can't I ^^ I just meant your code just does `QueueNode * deQueue(TQueue *q) { return q->first; }` and nothing more ^^